# 404 href error PHP script

Tags: php, laravel, http-status-code-404

Im new to laravel, but im trying to integrate an existing php script that I have into the laravel app. I understand everything happens in a MVC based architecture. However,im trying to link this page into the header page whose path is `application/view/templates/header.php`.

For example, there is a controller present in `application/controller/LoginController.php` and that has a function called `public function index()` and the way which it is called from `header`template is:

```
 <li <?php if (View::checkForActiveControllerAndAction($filename, "login/register")) { echo ' class="active" '; } ?> >
 <a href="<?php echo Config::get('URL'); ?>login/register">Register</a>
 </li>

 <li>
 <a href="admin.php">Administrator Login</a>
 </li>
```

As you can see when i try to call a script which is in the `root` directory, called `admin.php` it gives me a `404 - Page not found`.

Im really struggling I hope someone can help me figure out the problem. A 404 error is never fun as it is only a tiny error.

Comment: I would suggested specified the version of Laravel you're using.

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to run a basic PHP script then you can always chuck it in the public directory or try routing it from somewhere else. You're using it as a login script for admins so I would highly suggest just reprogramming it to be a part of your laravel site. Totally up to you though, this may not be the best answer but it will work.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest do it step by step

## Route

In your `/app/Http/routes.php`

```
Route::get('/login/register', 'LoginController@index');
```

---

## Controller

Let make sure you create a `LoginController.php` in `/app/Http/Controllers/`

---

## Function

In your `/app/Http/Controllers/LoginController.php` , create a function call index to return a view.

```
public function index(){
    return view('templates.header); // <-------- /templates/header.blade.php
}
```

---

## View

inside your `/resources/views/templates` create `header.blade.php`

Place all the HTML code needed in it

---

## Test

go to `http://localhost/login/register`

should load what you place in side your `header.blade.php`

You shouldn't get `404` anymore.